# Django - enforcing ManyToManyField unique items

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to do something simple like this:

```
members = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, null=True, unique=True)
```

but unique isn't allowed. When looking at the table created, it makes foreign keys so uniqueness is implied I imagine.

I want to be able to associate members with this model representing a group.  The group can have no members but I don't want the same member to be able to join the group twice.

My thought would be that an exception would be thrown if I try and do this but it seems that an exception is not thrown.

```
def join(request,id):
    user = request.user
    mygroup = Group.objects.get(id=id)
    mygroup.members.add(user)
    mygroup.num_members += 1
    mygroup.save()
```

num_members is incremented, because no exception is thrown.  Duplicate users don't appear in the admin utility. Does `add()` fail silently?  Should I just simply check if the user is contained already before adding?

Comment: Why don't you do a foreign key from the group to the user? this way a user can be on several groups, but only once on each group - which is what you wanted.

Comment: A `ForeignKey` from group to user means that there is only one user in a group.  `ForeignKey` is many-to-one.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

For one, I wouldn't use `num_members`. Instead, you can check how many members there are with `mygroup.members.count()`. Secondly, adding members more than once doesn't really add them more than once, so you're fine.

A `ManyToManyField` on `Group` for `member` pointing to `User` is implemented with a separate table (something like `group_group_users`) which has a foreign key to `Group` and `User`. A user can have multiple groups, and a group can have multiple users, but there can't be two rows in `group_group_users` for the same relationship (ie, unique together foreign keys).

Usage:

```
>>> group = Group.objects.get(pk=1)
>>> user = User.objects.get(pk=1)
>>> group.members.add(user)
>>> # Worked fine as expected. Let's check the results.
>>> group.members.all()
[<User: foousername>]
>>> group.members.add(user)
>>> # Worked fine again. Let's check for duplicates.
>>> group.members.all()
[<User: foousername>]
>>> # Worked fine.
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for.  Why shouldn't I use id?

Comment: @JPC - you can, but it's a good practice to use `pk`. It maps to the primary key, whether your primary key is named `id` or `identity`, etc.

Comment: @JPC - oh, that `id`. The reason you shouldn't use `id` as a method parameter is because `id` is a build-in Python function.

Comment: @JPC How would you enable having multiple references to the same object then? Not sensible in the context of your example, of course, but anyway?

Comment: Ok found it. A join table has to be created. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2350855/my-django-manytomany-fields-are-all-marked-unique-is-there-an-option-to-remove

Answer (score 17):

> Duplicate users don't appear in the admin utility.

They're not created.

> Does add() fail silently?

Yes.

> Should I just simply check if the user is contained already before adding?

Yes. Or instead of manually counting the users, you could just have the database count for you:

```
mygroup = Group.objects.filter(...).annotate(num_members=models.Count("members"))
```

This eliminates the need for a `num_members` field in the actual model.

Also, you shouldn't use `id` as a parameter name to your function.

Comment: P.S.  `mygroup.members.count()` runs a single SQL query to get a count (`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ...`) while the `annotate` method I've shown lets you query several groups at once with `Group.objects.filter(...)` and get member counts for each group, all in one SQL query instead of one per group.  And having a parameter named `id` hides the built-in function of the same name.

Comment: checking if the user is already contained is not guarenteed to work because of the concurency

Comment: True in general, and checking beforehand doesn't remove the need to catch errors. Here it matters if you'll have concurrent use of the admin. If so, you'll have to do some thinking to resolve questions like, "If one user adds someone to a group they're already in, but in the meantime another user removes that someone from said group, should the someone be in the group or not?" IMHO, the answer is "it doesn't matter; this is a failure of coordination at the user level and each possible outcome is correct to only one user."