# How do you save a relationship with an existing tag otherwise create the tag, in django views?

Tags: django, models, tagging

In a many to many tagging system; how do you save a photo to the name of the tag already exists and still save the photo with the rest of the tags added through the form.

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    title = models.TextField(blank=False, null=True)
    path = models.FileField(blank=False, null=True, upload_to='photos/')


class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(blank=False, null=True)
    photos = models.ManyToManyField(Photo)
```

Heres an example from the view that will raise an error with Tag.name unique=true.
**Granted there exists a photo foo with a tag bar.**

```
photo = Photo(title='foo2')
photo.save()
bar = form.data['tag'] ** this is tag bar
bar = Tag(name=bar)
bar.save() **will raise error, name bar already exists so you cannot save it
bar.photos.add(instance)
```

Comment: It seems like you just want `unique=True` on the Tag model, then use `Tag.objects.get_or_create()`. Is there more to your question than this?

Comment: unique=True on the name, will allow the name be unique but will raise an error if you try to add another photo with that tag.  So from here I can rephrase the question to: How to save another photo to that same tag? with the tag being unique

Comment: Is the tag named by the user? so you problem is if the user create a tag which has already existed in the tag table, the form cant save it? if you provide more details about your business logic, people can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I apologize for reviving this old question and being contrary, but I thought it might help for me to provide a full code snippet. I've mentioned `get_or_create` a couple times but either you're misunderstanding me or vice versa. This code should be the same as what you wrote, except it uses Django's `get_or_create` rather than reinventing it and needing to catch the `IntegrityError`:

```
instance = Photo(title=form.data['title'])
instance.save()
tag, created = Tag.objects.get_or_create(name=form.data['tags'])
tag.photos.add(instance)
return HttpResponse("Succesful Upload with Tags")
```

Hope this helps. :-)

Comment: old, but was looking back at my questions. i switched my response to accept this one as the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm mistaken, the tag 'bar' *will* be connected to both foo and foo2. The way ManyToMany fields in Django work is by creating an extra table, where each entry has a foreign key to both of the things it connects to.

So, in your example, it would create a table `photo_photo_tag`, with a foreign key to a `Photo` and a foreign key to a `Tag`. Thus, the tag itself is only saved once in the `tag` table, but referenced by foreign key many times in `photo_photo_tag`.

For more information on how ManyToMany works, see the following:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/
[Django - enforcing ManyToManyField unique items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870935/django-enforcing-manytomanyfield-unique-items)

Comment: That I know and explained, my question is how can I architect it to create unique names but still save the relationship to that name

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was, adding setting the Tag model's name to unique.  Then in the view doing a try on the save.  If the name exists; it will still save the relation to that tag names id

```
        instance = Photo(title=form.data['title'])
        instance.save()
        tag = form.data['tags']
        tag = Tag(name=tag)
            try:
                tag.save() **if the tag is unique, it will save it then add relation
                tag.photos.add(instance)
            except IntegrityError, e:  ** if its not unique, grab the ID of that tag
                tag_id = Tag.objects.all().filter(name=tag)
                singletag = tag_id[0]
                singletag.photos.add(instance)  ** then add relation
        return HttpResponse("Succesful Upload with Tags")
```

Comment: This looks like you reinvented `Tag.objects.get_or_create()` which is what I suggested above. In other words: `tag, created = Tag.objects.get_or_create(name=tag); tag.photos.add(instance)`

Comment: The issue was more so trying to saving a photo to a unique tag name if the tag already exists. I rephrased the question for any other future references. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I think we are still misunderstanding each other, and I couldn't explain adequately in a comment, so I added another answer.