# Why can't uniqueness be enforced on Django ManyToMany field?

Tags: python, django, django-models, models, rating

I'm creating a simple binary rating system for my website, it is a study materials website with summaries that can be rated +1 or -1.

I've defined to ManyToMany fields between my Summary model and User model like so:

```
users_rated_positive = models.ManyToManyField(
    User, blank=True, related_name='summaries_rated_positive')
users_rated_negative = models.ManyToManyField(
    User, blank=True, related_name='summaries_rated_negative')
```

However it is obvious that a given user can not rate a given summary more than once.

I tried setting unique=True but Django doesn't seem to let me do that.

Is there are more optimal way to store the ratings that aligns better with my intentions?

Comment: Did you check that you can effectively add duplicate relations ? This answer seems to imply that duplicate relations are not permitted:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870935/django-enforcing-manytomanyfield-unique-items

Comment: so I don't need to actually check this in my view?

Comment: I never tried it myself so cannot be sure, but this is what is described in the answer I linked. You may try to reproduce the test case that is in the answer to check.

Answer (score 4):

Consider using a ManyToMany [through table](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships).

```
class Summary(models.Model):
    user_ratings = models.ManyToManyField(
        'User', blank=True, through='UserRating',
    )


class UserRating(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('User')
    summary = models.ForeignKey('Summary')
    is_positive = models.BooleanField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('user', 'summary')
```

Then you can query users who reviewed the summary positively with something like

```
summary.user_ratings.filter(is_positive=True)
summary.user_ratings.filter(is_positive=False)
```

The `unique_together` property ensures that a user can't review the same summary twice.

You could even retain similar syntax using a custom queryset. Here's a guess at what that might look like:

```
class SummaryQuerySet(models.QuerySet):

    def users_rated_negative(self):
        return self.user_ratings.filter(is_positive=False)

    def users_rated_positive(self):
        return self.user_ratings.filter(is_positive=True)


class Summary(models.Model):
    user_ratings = models.ManyToManyField(
        'User', blank=True, through='UserRating',
    )

    objects = SummaryQuerySet.as_manager()
```

Now the in-use syntax is `summary.users_rated_positive`

A similar custom queryset for `User` would give you the `summaries_rated_positive` property, if you needed that too.