# On a django model, how to check uniqueness in the set of values in a ManyToMany field?

Tags: python, django, django-models

For example if I have a set of models like this, how can I make sure that only one `Group` instance with the same exact set of `Permission`s could exist in the model?

```
class Permission(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)

class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    permissions = models.ManyToManyField(Permission)

class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
```

What is the best way to enforce this constraint in django? I don't care about a DB-level constraint. Does django provide an existing flag on the `ManyToMany` model field or I need to add custom data validation? And if yes, how?

Also I don't use `ModelForm`s, so form validation is not what I want.

My question is about uniqueness of set of `ManyToMany` field relations across the whole model, not in a single instance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django - enforcing ManyToManyField unique items](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870935/django-enforcing-manytomanyfield-unique-items)

Comment: @doru No, that question is not the same. Because the accepted answer assumes what I want is the default behaviour in Django, which is not. My question is about uniqueness of set of `ManyToMany` field relations across the whole model, not in a single instance.

Answer (score 1):

You can override the `Group` model's `save` method in order to check uniqueness before saving `Group` objects.

For example:

```
class Group(models.Model):
    ...
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if insert_your_check_here():
            super(Group, self).save(*args, **kwargs) # Call the "real" save() method.
        else:
            return
```

For more information about overriding predefined model methods take a look at the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods).