# Efficiently retrieve from and add to ManyToManyField

Tags: django

I have two models, let's say Container and Item. Container has a ManyToMany field to associate Containers to Items. I want to add an Item to a Container and then list all of the Items in this container. However, I've noticed that Django queries for each item before it adds it, therefore I end up with three queries, one to get all of the Items, one to check if the Item I want to add is there, and another to add the Item. Is there a way to eliminate this superfluous checking?

I've tried replacing the item_set entirely using the set command but it still adds the extra check for duplicates.

```py
# Select all items in item_set
existing = container.item_set.all()
# Select item in item_set (even though we know) and insert item into set
container.item_set.add(new_item)
```

In brief: I would like to end up with a new item added to the set and all the old items from the set in two queries

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to check if the relationship exists before adding a new item to the many-to-many relationships. Adding an item to an already existing relationship will not result a new row being added. You can refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4871075/6890912) for details.

In other words, you can safely add the item without checking first and then perform a retrieval:

```
container.item_set.add(new_item)
items = container.item_set.all()
```

Comment: No, I'm not checking manually. But when you do item_set.add(new_item) and then check django.db.connection.queries, it makes a SELECT and an INSERT query.